# Alamofire 5 Any In Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to make a post request with Alamofire 5. I have to use `Dictionary<String, Any>` for parameters. Because I am writing a wrapper for Alamofire. But it seems i can't be able to use Any object in a dictionary because Alamofire gives me a compiler error:

```
Value of protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Encodable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
```

What i've tried:

```
    let encodedParameters = Dictionary<String, Any>

    AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: encodedParameters, headers: headers)
```

Some values will be string others will be integer in my dictionary. So i can't use constant type. How can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the new `request`, you can create your own structs for your request parameters:

```
// you might have...
struct FooRequestParameters : Codable {
    let paramName1: Int
    let paramName2: String
}

// for another type of request, you might have different parameters...
struct BarRequestParameters: Codable {
    let somethingElse: Bool
}
```

And you can pass a `FooRequestParameters(paramName1: 1, paramName1: "hello")` instead of your dictionary. This would be the same as passing the dictionary:

```
[
    "paramName1": 1,
    "paramName2": "hello"
]
```

The rationale behind this API change is likely to have more safety. With a `[String: Any]`, you could very easily, say, give a `String` value to a parameter that is supposed to be `Int`, or type a parameter's name wrongly, or missed some parameters without realising... etc etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am just trying to figuring out, what is the best practice for managing these structs? Should i define all of them in one file?

Comment: @TolgayToklar I think it's up to your preferences and your coding style. For me, I'd like to put them in the same file as I send the request, if I only send the request in only one place. Otherwise I would put it in a file on its own.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i have just found the solution before your comment, this is why i had deleted the comment

Answer (score 4):

It's because you are using the newer method which requires the `parameters` parameter to be `Encodable`.Use the older Alamofire method and you will be fine:

```
AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: encodedParameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
```

Update: If you want to use the latest Alamofire 5 syntax create a struct and confirm it to encodable. Then create an object of the same struct with values and pass it.

Comment: Yeah, i know that but i am searching for alamofire 5 way

Comment: For alamofire 5 you have to make a struct confirm it to Encodable and pass it's object.

Comment: So than i have to create many structs for every other api requests?

Comment: Yes, unless you're passing the same set of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you want pass parameters of `[String: Any]` you don't need to create `structs` and adopt the `encodable` protocol. This can be achieved like this:

```swift
import Foundation
import Alamofire

enum ServiceRouter {
    case fetchCountries
    case fetchUserRepositories
    
    var baseURL: String {
        switch self {
        case .fetchCountries:
            return "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2"
        }
    }
    
    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .fetchCountries:
            return "/all"
        }
    }
    
    var method: HTTPMethod {
        switch self {
        case .fetchCountries:
            return .get
        default:
            return .post
        }
    }
    
    var parameters: Parameters? {
        switch self {
        case .fetchUserRepositories:
            return ["per_page": 100]
            
        default:
            return [:]
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - URLRequestConvertible
extension ServiceRouter: URLRequestConvertible {
    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        let url = try baseURL.asURL().appendingPathComponent(path)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.method = method
        if method == .get {
            request = try URLEncoding.default.encode(request, with: parameters)
        } else if method == .post {
            request = try JSONEncoding.default.encode(request, with: parameters)
        }
        return request
    }
}
```

And you can use this request as

```
AF.request(ServiceRouter.fetchCountries).responseData { (response) in
```

Answer (score 0):

With the Alamofire 5 you can use this with Any type

```swift
AF.request("{url}", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted).response { response in
        print(response)
}
```

I hope this helps someone

Comment: The server doesn't care at all if the JSON is *pretty printed*. Only humans do. Omit the parameter. 